# 16.04 dependencies problem

Tags: apt, package-management

I built a new PC and I installed Ubuntu 16.04 desktop 64bit. So it's a fresh install, not an upgrade.

I installed a couple of my favorite software from the official repos, and I enabled canonical partners.

After that I wanted to install Synthing, so I followed the instruction on this page : http://apt.syncthing.net/ and added their repo.

I also installed the latest Discord native app (.deb package) from the github page : https://github.com/crmarsh/discord-linux-bugs

Now, I have errors when I try to install something from the official repos, for example here's what I get when I try to install Samba (sorry for the french):

```
sudo apt install samba
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
samba : Dépend: python-samba mais ne sera pas installé
     Dépend: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.3.3+dfsg-1ubuntu3) mais ne sera pas installé
     Dépend: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.3.3+dfsg-1ubuntu3) mais 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 devra être installé
     Dépend: samba-libs (= 2:4.3.3+dfsg-1ubuntu3) mais 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 devra être installé
     Recommande: attr
     Recommande: samba-vfs-modules mais ne sera pas installé
     Recommande: samba-dsdb-modules mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

partial translation attempt :

```
Some pacckages contains unsatisfiable dependencies :
Samba : Depend: python-samba but will not be installed
     Depend: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.3.3+dfsg-1ubuntu3) but will not be installed
...
E: Impossible to resolve problems, some broken packages are in mode « keep as it is ».
```

How can I proceed to troubleshoot this problem? thanks

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: Same error message with sudo apt install -f samba

Comment: Can you please translate that?

Comment: I edited my post to add a translation. I get the same kind of errors if I try to install Steam (also in official repositories)

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` recently? What's the output of `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX apt-cache policy samba samba-libs`? Please use the `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX` command prefix like before to receive English program messages so that all readers on AskUbuntu can understand them. :-)

Comment: Result of apt-cache policy samba samba-libs: http://paste.ofcode.org/34DQ9f6p3Qahjjp3E59qWgP

Thanks, you reminded me that I changed the default source URL to http://archive.ubuntu.csg.uzh.ch which is the first server suggested for Switzerland. I changed for http://mirror.switch.ch and now everything seems to be alright.

I guess archive.ubuntu.csg.uzh.ch are not providing the right packages or something like this. Where should I report this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem : http://archive.ubuntu.csg.uzh.ch one of the repository for Switzerland is completely out of date.

I switched to http://mirror.switch.ch who is up to date and everything is all right again.